# date.getTime() difference problem

Tags: java, gettime

Greetings,

I have one simple condition that never passes:

```
if(datas.date.getTime()-temps.date.getTime()>=5000)
```

I want to check if it has been 5 seconds from one to another.

---

**Update**:

Here is setter and getter:

```
public class Data{
    Date date;
    public Date getDate() {
        return date;
    }
    public void setDate() {
        Date now = new Date();
        this.date = now;
    }
}
```

So, I call

```
Data data;
data.setDate();
processValues(data);
```

this is processValues:

```
public void processValues(Data dat){

    if(datas.size()==7){
        writeValues(datas);
        datas=new Vector<Data>();
        temps=new Vector<Data>();
    }
    temps.add(dat);
    datas.add(dat);
}
```

this is writeValues:

```
public void writeValues(Vector<Data> datas){
    for(i=0;i<temps.size();i++)
        for(j=0;j<datas.size();j++){
            if(temps.elementAt(i).epc==datas.elementAt(j).epc)
                if(datas.elementAt(j).date.getTime()-temps.elementAt(i).date.getTime()>=5000)
                    try {
                        dao.writeToDatabase(datas.elementAt(j));
                        i=j;
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
        }

}
```

Comment: datas and temps are objects that have Date date in them. These are getter and setter: public Date getDate() {
  return date;
 }
 public void setDate() {
  Date now = new Date();
  this.date = now;
 }

Comment: if you output the value of datas.date.getTime()-temps.date.getTime(), what do you get? A common mistake is for your calculation to be the wrong way round, and the value is negative

Comment: Leaving out the braces from your `for` and `if` blocks is a great way to introduce hard-to-spot bugs

Answer (score 0):

If you output `datas.date.getTime()` and `temps.date.getTime()`, which one is higher?  My guess is that they are reversed and the subtraction is giving a negative number - which of course would never be greater than 5000.  Or the data points aren't 5 seconds apart.

Comment: They are in correct order, and are 5 seconds apart after few iterations. I always get same number for both, so they give 0 divided

Comment: @Clark Kent: If you always get the same number for both, then they can't ever be 5 seconds apart ...

Comment: Can you show how you are setting it that is giving you the same number?  Maybe there is a bug in the code?  If the two are always the same, the error is in code outside this line in particular and more information is needed to help with your problem.

Answer (score 0):

You say you have a getter that looks like this:

```
public Date getDate() {
    return date;
}
```

`Date` objects are mutable, so you should probably copy defensively. You can use `clone()` for this.

Based on that and the syptoms of your problem, perhaps your two `Date` objects are actually the same  object. Have you tried using `==` (or `!=`) to confirm that they are indeed separate objects?

## Update

Based on the updated information I can see why that condition never passes. I don't really understand what you want you code to do, however. You're essentially just testing if you can create 7 objects in less than 5 seconds, and if you can't then you write some of them out. Either way you clear `temps` and `datas`, whether you wrote the objects out or not. My guess is that you do not want to clear these vectors of elements that were not written out. I also don;t understnad why you have both `datas` and `temps` when they contain exactly the same elements.

Comment: First I call (from other class) data.setDate(); and then I have method processValues(data) that fills vector with objects. datas and temps are indeed same vectors and actually this condition looks like if(datas.elementAt(j).date.getTime()-temps.elementAt(i).date.getTime()>=5000) I iterate through both of them to find where is next object that has difference in time > 5s. When I try to print values, they are all the same for all objects in vector...

Comment: The isue isn't whetehr they're in the same vector, but whether they're the same Date objects. Is this expression ever false?  `datas.elementAt(j) == temps.elementAt(i)` If it is always true then that's your bug.

Comment: I posted some more info, please take a look

Answer (score 0):

You said that your processValues() method looks like this:

```
public void processValues(Data dat){
    if(datas.size()==7){
        writeValues(datas);
        datas=new Vector<Data>();
        temps=new Vector<Data>();
    }
    temps.add(dat);
    datas.add(dat);
}
```

You're adding the same instance ("dat") to both vectors. If you update one it will necessarily update the other, so there can never be a difference in the `date` field.

Comment: I know, but why are dates inside one vector same??? Vectors are supposed to be identical, but every object should have different date. They are all same Date objects inside. Is it problem with setter?

Comment: The dates are the same because there is only one Data object. A date cannot be different from itself ;-)

Comment: Sorry, it's impossible to say without understanding what you're trying to do, and this is very unclear from your code. For example, the `Data` class appears to be completely pointless since it just wraps an instance of `Date`.